# Making glitch photos

Tags: photo-editing, distort, glitch

How can i make **glitch** photos like this picture?

[image: distorted photo]

Is there any special software or programming language to make photos like this?

Comment: Nearly any image editor can do this. Look for distort filters.

Comment: While I don't think the web apps mentioned in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/116533/2332) can create something stretched out like that, you might be able to get you results you like.

Answer (score 0):

Only loose guidance without shown own attempts

Try the following:

- make the canvas bigger to have room
- make your image a layer, do not let it be the background
- make mirrored copies of the face to up and down
- apply warping + liquify and waves filters for distortions, not globally, only on limited areas
- distort R,G and B channels a little differently here and there to create the chromatic aberration.
- create a horizontal gap by moving half of the image layer upwards, fill the gap by stretching a narrow slice at the edge of the gap

If you can work these, you are a gone a long way towards independent working. Good luck!