# Photoshop glitched, but I liked it, and now want to script it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, glitch

I was trying to *File* → *Place Embedded* this [Youtube video screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/413lE.jpg) into a Photoshop file and it kept glitching, each time differently.

Here are two examples of what it looked like. This is a whole new level of entropy, randomness and abstraction which I won't be able to accomplish manually even if I tried.

---

[image: Imgur]

---

[image: Imgur]

---

**I'm wondering if there's any way to take this under control?**

This could probably be done using scripts cutting out and repeating random portions of an image and applying colour overlay effects to it? I've been working with Javascript a lot, but I'm new to Photoshop scripting and unsure what is it capable of. Just to clarify: this is not so much about applying a glitch effect (which I'm sure there are many). I'm specifically interested in randomly rearranging the composition to where you can't recognise the original anymore. You should be able to see some parts of it though, and the *scripting* portion of this question was supposed to address how many meaningful areas are copied by using variables for example.

Do you think this is doable? If so, how?

I still have the file, so if something needs clarifying, please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any method to deliberately digitally corrupt an image?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116532/is-there-any-method-to-deliberately-digitally-corrupt-an-image)

Comment: @Danielillo appreciate your input, but what I'm seeing in the post you shared is completely different: they distort the image *while maintaining it's structure and composition*, however in my case it's rearranged to the point where you can't even recognise and link it to the original.

Comment: It looks like certain RGB channels are maxed out – a different channel for each rectangle. That explains the whiteouts: all channels set to 255,255,255. It's hard to see, though, if the rectangles themselves are shuffled as well.

Comment: If that's happening using the image you linked to.... it's a sign of a failing RAM or a failing video card.

Comment: @Scott positive, it is that exact image. However I opened it in Preview and resaved as JPEG, and it worked fine.

Comment: I posted a link to an article in that question Danielle linked to. It's possible to get something like your example image by deliberately copputing the image, thought it's a little bit guess work as far as I know.

Comment: Closest I could find: [1](https://graphicriver.net/item/glitch-bundle-photoshop-actions/20695098), [2](https://graphicriver.net/item/glitch-art-photoshop-actions/11455182), [3](https://graphicriver.net/item/glitch-art-photoshop-action/19032075). They don't destroy the photo as much as you seem to want, but I would assume you could get there by running one of those a few times on one photo... or I guess those actions could be adjusted to be more drastic.